# wget/curl download of Oracle Java 7 SDK from the Oracle Archive page

Tags: java, curl, wget

There are plenty of posts on StackOverflow and other communities (AskUbuntu, Unix & Linux etc.) which provide advice on how to use `wget` or `cUrl` to automate downloading a Java distribution from the Oracle website. They all involve sending a cookie which pretends that one accepted the license agreement which one usually has to to manually before the real download link appears.

However, none of these work for me when trying to download Java 7 SDK which recently has been moved to the [Oracle Archive page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html).

If I go to this page, accept the license agreement manually and then copy a download link, it looks like this:

`http://download.oracle.com/otn/java/jdk/7u80-b15/jdk-7u80-linux-x64.tar.gz`

**Note that it has `otn` in the middle while all the other posts are about URLs which are stored under`otn-pub`.**

Using the usual way that worked for the `otn-pub` links looks like this:

`wget --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=a" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u80-b15/jdk-7u80-linux-x64.tar.gz`

However, this does not work for the `otn` type of URL. Instead, `wget` returns:

```
--2017-05-23 12:11:12--  http://download.oracle.com/otn/java/jdk/7u80-b15/jdk-7u80-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 92.122.214.233, 92.122.214.217
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|92.122.214.233|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/akam/otn/java/jdk/7u80-b15/jdk-7u80-linux-x64.tar.gz [following]
--2017-05-23 12:11:12--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/akam/otn/java/jdk/7u80-b15/jdk-7u80-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 23.0.39.115, 2a02:26f0:8f:29a::2d3e
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|23.0.39.115|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://login.oracle.com/pls/orasso/orasso.wwsso_app_admin.ls_login?Site2pstoreToken=v1.2~CA55CD32~5B4FBD9FD4FC906722CB92CC3F7FA417B904138FD53F875C3FEFDF932EC5928D866C8B39EACAA55F28099E034BAC612F869C90A39B20E322E380F4A006B9668EAD35323A1C548EAD5D03EE8D6C772A88C049F024986DC6CCF546B00D347731F76BE786B96F0041610DEE7B6B4EAC27DCBE558B151B032973F065FC0367918B72DBCAB4B7FC920BAC4C13E820DFFE1761C5C473B6E0A4F0E94FABACDB40F02AD6B2BAB1D3F57371B14048557A0291AC3F12C73A30CAF4AAEB8A545475300A1ABBD60E2BF27FB1B11BC47DE91D0E918E04E4C4663632E98752BBC07671BBD21E7C6F73D78A8A66254579EC63B99716D999 [following]
--2017-05-23 12:11:12--  https://login.oracle.com/pls/orasso/orasso.wwsso_app_admin.ls_login?Site2pstoreToken=v1.2~CA55CD32~5B4FBD9FD4FC906722CB92CC3F7FA417B904138FD53F875C3FEFDF932EC5928D866C8B39EACAA55F28099E034BAC612F869C90A39B20E322E380F4A006B9668EAD35323A1C548EAD5D03EE8D6C772A88C049F024986DC6CCF546B00D347731F76BE786B96F0041610DEE7B6B4EAC27DCBE558B151B032973F065FC0367918B72DBCAB4B7FC920BAC4C13E820DFFE1761C5C473B6E0A4F0E94FABACDB40F02AD6B2BAB1D3F57371B14048557A0291AC3F12C73A30CAF4AAEB8A545475300A1ABBD60E2BF27FB1B11BC47DE91D0E918E04E4C4663632E98752BBC07671BBD21E7C6F73D78A8A66254579EC63B99716D999
Resolving login.oracle.com (login.oracle.com)... 209.17.4.8
Connecting to login.oracle.com (login.oracle.com)|209.17.4.8|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Authorization Required

Username/Password Authentication Failed.
```

Looks like either they changed something regarding the authentication or it never worked before for links from the `Oracle Archive` page (never tried that before).

Any idea how I can download the most recent Oracle Java 7 SDK .tar.gz archive using `wget` or `cUrl` or similar?

Comment: If you cannot make this work, consider switching to Zulu.  http://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu/zulu-linux/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The oracle site asks you to login if you try to download JDK 7 from their archive. Hence the issue with the curl and wget. This is a recent change hope they can change this.

Note: Oracle has changed their licensing policy so check that before you move ahead. Your JDK may not be free anymore

Comment: I really don't see how this can be helpful. kixx's answer below does the trick.

Comment: If you read the OP question - the problem is accessing archives. Kixx answer works *only* for otn-pub links which host absolutely latest versions of JDKs/JREs (like latest verisons of JDK8 and JDK9). However if you want to reproduce a runtime env that matches your prod where you have not yet upgraded to latest version, you need to go through Archive. As Arun Ganesan mentioned - you won't be able to do it via curl from archive. So while it doesnt solve the problem - it explains why this isn't possible.

Answer (score 7):

wget has worked with the otn-pub link up until recently.It does seem that Oracle has changed something.

The closest workaround is to wget from another site that host it

```
wget http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/funtoo/distfiles/oracle-java/jdk-7u80-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't answer the OP's problem. This is the easiest solution. You don't have to use ftp.osuosl.org, but "download it from some other host" is the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

This curl command works for me:

```
curl -v -O -L -b oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u131-b11/d54c1d3a095b4ff2b6607d096fa80163/jdk-8u131-linux-i586.rpm
```

options:

- **-v** - just display additional info and HTTP headers on STDERR (you can skip this) or use **-s** for silent run
- **-O** - save response to disk (instead of sending it to STDOUT) or use **-o** *filename* to specify another path
- **-L** - follow redirects
- **-b** - enable cookie engine and pass in initial cookie *oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie*

The URL is lifted straight from the Oracle JDK download page

Comment: Unfortunate that the hash(?) in there will probably break with the next release :-/ Wishing there was a consistent/predictable URL structure.

Comment: Where exactly did you get this URL from, please? Your `cUrl` command does not work for me when trying on an URL from the `otn` page space (not `otn-pub`), as given in the question.

Comment: @Dirk `otn-pub` requires the user to accept the license agreement and generates a random hash within the URL. `otn` requires Oracle login credentials. `curl` won't work with `otn`.

Comment: Only JDK7 requires username/password. You use JDK8.

Comment: 1. Go to the Oracle download page.
2. Accept the license.
3. Copy the download URL.
4. Use URL in above curl command.

It worked for me seconds ago :)

Answer (score 1):

Oracle doesn't allow download from archive link without login into the portal and also its not recommendable to use jdk from archive links.

Check this link for more info:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/archive-139210.html